# Phpunit newbie - how to get assertTrue method

Tags: phpunit

How do I get assertTrue method?  My file phpunit_test.php is

```
<?php

class phptest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
  public function test_something()
  {
    $this->assertTrue{ 1 > 0 };
  }  
}
?>
```

but phpunit phpunit_test.php returns

```
There was 1 error:

1) phptest::test_something
Undefined property: phptest::$assertTrue
```

Comment: Just to ensure you know, your test will not throw an assertion since  1 is greater than 0, so it passes the test without an error.  The asserts fail tests that do not return what is being checked.  Think of an assertTrue as being throw an assertion (error) if the condition is NOT true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 $this->assertTrue{ 1 > 0 };
```

should be

```
 $this->assertTrue( 1 > 0 );
```